# Possible to make Android tablet app auto-update with no human interaction?

Tags: android, cordova, tablet, auto-update

I've written a custom Android app that uses Cordova and runs on a custom, non-touchscreen tablet that requires USB mouse and keyboard to be interfaced with. I have several dozen of these tablets, and needless to say, it's a real pain to install app updates on all of them. Please note that this app is always running on the devices, and the app starts on boot. The devices also auto-reboot themselves once daily.

I'd like an auto-update solution -- something where the app will update itself automatically (unsupervised), say, once per day, when there is an update. And I totally understand that the app will need to stop running prior to updating (and start again following the update). I'm also totally cool with a programmatic update (where I build this functionality myself).

Does anyone know of a way to auto-update an Android app with no human interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Android does have auto-update pushes, which when a new update is present, it will push it to the device.

**Automatically update apps**

- Open the Google Play Store Google Play Store app.
- Touch the Google Play Store Play Store icon > My Apps to view your
  downloaded apps. Apps with available updates are labeled "Update."
- Select the app you want to update.
- Touch  Menu >  Check the box next to "Auto-update" (depending on your
  device, your Menu icon may look different).

  - When the Auto-update box is selected, the app will update
    automatically when updates are available.
  - To turn off automatic updates and manually approve updates,  uncheck the box next to
    "Auto-update".

**Automatically update apps using Wi-Fi only (not using 3G/4G)**

1. Open the Google Play Store Google Play Store app.
2. Touch the  Google Play Store Play Store icon > Settings.
3. Under "General," select Auto-update apps.
4. Select Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only.

For more information about android autoupdates see this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en

[image: Automatic update menu image]

If you wanted to auto-update without using the android market, you should take a look at [cwac-updater](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater).

Comment: Will the apps auto-restart as well? Or will the new version load only when the device reboots or the app is manually reloaded?

Comment: they won't autorestart

Comment: you increment your Version Code when you make an update to your app. It will detect the version number difference and update the app in the background, when the app isn't running it will update. @rupps is right, your app won't auto-restart if it is already open.

Comment: You can possibly do a [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) push to the client app to force it to restart with [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Comment: @Beau Bouchard From my research, it seems it is impossible to auto-update without a prompt. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369932/automatically-update-an-android-app-without-requiring-user-interaction. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ChadJohnson the application will indeed need to restart/ have some sort of interaction in-order to update. The auto-update features that google provides with play-store is intended for casual use and requires some interaction as well.  Perhaps you can ask the question at http://android.stackexchange.com/